Why is my visual studio showing c++ when debugging?
I am currently programming in C# in Visual Studio. That started well.
When I start debugging and observe an object with a watch during a break, values are shown in C++, meaning It shows nullptr or myObject^ pointers. It's the same when I directly observe a field value during a break.
How do I change it back to C#? I found nothing in the options menu or with the search feature (maybe because I can't formulate it right).
I found that my code in the call stack shows as C++, but I don't know why.

How can that be?

I found it!! It's because I regrouped the files in folders. One of these folders had an accent in its name. Replacing the accentuated letter with its basic form solved the problem for me.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
